# How to get the second word in string in emacs lisp?

Tags: elisp

`(message %s)` > "foo bar"

How can I only print "bar"?

Answer (score 2):

First split the string, then grab the element you want from the resulting list:

```
(message "%s" (nth 1 (split-string "foo bar")))
```